# Change Google Chrome cache size on OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser-cache

How can I change the cache size Google Chrome uses? ON OS X?
I've found countless posts how do to things on Windows but couldn't really figure out from that how to do things on os x.

Help will be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: By the way, the maximum number you can set is 2147483647. Otherwise it would complain not convertible to integer(It's stored as an signed integer in Chrome).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to launch it from the command line with the following flag `--disk-cache-size=524288000`, where `524288000` is the upper limit of what it could be set to.
You could try to make a script that launches it with the augment.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disk-cache-size=524288000 &
```

Then name it with a `.sh` extension, and `chmod u+x /path/to/file.sh` and you should be good.

Comment: Is there no way to add the argument to the default shortcut? :/

Comment: To my knowledge, apple doesn't make it easy to use run time flags with GUI apps; which is why I suggested writing a short script.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to create a plist file com.google.Chrome.plist in /Library/Preferences with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>DiskCacheSize</key>
    <integer>524288000</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Good. It would have been easier to point out that the number meant 500MB. This is a better method as it doesn;t sideStep if you start Chrome via Launcher. On a similar note, is stuff in /Library/Preferences deleted when you upgrade Mac OSX?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome DiskCacheSize -integer 3145728000
```

to set it to 3GB.

Comment: Any way to validate this is working?

Comment: does it count for total cache size or per profile?